# Facebook Desktop AIR Graph API - Actionscript 3 - Login as page and post photo on page wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, air

Do you know how can I login as a page and post a photo on wall of this page?
I can post on wall, but the photo don't appears just the text.
Thanks!

Code:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(mc_photo.width, mc_photo.height);
            bitmapData.draw(mc_photo);  
            var bitmap:Bitmap=new Bitmap(bitmapData);

            var values:Object = {message:'My photo caption', fileName:'FILE_NAME',image:bitmap};

            FacebookDesktop.api('/253577334667618/photos', handleUploadComplete, values,'POST');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what your are doing wrong is the name of the parameter for the photo, 'image', because the value it should be 'picture':

```
var values:Object = {message:'My photo caption', fileName:'FILE_NAME',picture:bitmap};
```